# AutoCompleteTextView filter not working

Tags: android, autocomplete

I have two AutoCompleteTextView (group and instalation).

After I choose group, Instalation should filter the information depending on the group but it's not working.

If in the sql line i take out the WHERE part it works fine (but shows me all the information and i don't want that).

```
List<String> instalacao = new ArrayList<String>();
Cursor cursor=mydb.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT instalacao FROM registo WHERE grupo like '"+txGrupo.getText().toString()+"';",null);
while (cursor.moveToNext()){
    instalacao.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("instalacao")));  
}
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,instalacao);     
txInstalacao.setThreshold(0); 
txInstalacao.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The dropdown:

```
txInstalacao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        txInstalacao.showDropDown();
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match a prefix, you should use '%' at the end of the parameter.

```
"WHERE grupo like '" + txGrupo.getText().toString() + "%'"
```

As an aside, I would strongly recommend using the `query()` method instead of `rawquery()`. Building an SQL statement like this will lead to problems (for example if the contents of `txGrupo` contains quotes).

Comment: It's showing me all the values, it's not filtering anything :(

Comment: when i say like it could be '=' too.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why it wasnt showing anything. When i start the intent i call the method, at this time the TextField is empty so it has nothing there. when i choose my group i have to refresh the method and i was not doing that :)